# TypeScript with Relay: Can't resolve generated module

Tags: reactjs, typescript, relayjs

In my `MessageItem.tsx` component I have the following code:

```
const data = useFragment(
    graphql`
      fragment MessageItem_message on Message {
        date
        body
      }
    `,
    message as any
  );
```

After running `relay-compiler --src ./src --schema ../../schema.graphql --language typescript --artifactDirectory ./src/__generated__`, a module named `MessageItem_message.graphql.ts`  gets generated.

But when I run the app it gives me an error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/MessageItem.tsx
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve
>   './__generated__/MessageItem_message.graphql'

The reason is only components at the src root can refer to the right path (`./__generated__`), whereas components in a folder actually need to refer to the path (`../__generated__`) but it's not doing so.

How can I configure the path?

Comment: You can have a look on this issue: https://github.com/relay-tools/relay-compiler-language-typescript/issues/40

Comment: @StanleyLuo Any progress on this?  I've tried to setup absolute paths and configure throughout but still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `.babelrc` to point to the artifactDirectory

```json
// .babelrc
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "relay",
      {
        "artifactDirectory": "./src/ui/graphql/types"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove "--artifactDirectory  ./src/__generated__" from the relay-compiler options.

By default it seems the Relay compiler puts a "__generated__" directory in the directory with any source code containing GraphQL.

As a result any "./__generated__" references anywhere and at any level in the source code hierarchy now work as they should.

Thanks to @ThibaultBoursier for the pointer.

PS I wonder if the --artifcactDirectory option is just meant to be used to change the name of the artifact directory, rather than its location?

Answer (score 0):

Just moments ago I ran into the same issue. The reason is that the `relay-compiler` is using the `artifactDirectory` setting to decide where to put the generated files, but the `babel-plugin-relay` exposing the `graphql` tag needs to get the very same argument otherwise it just attempts to include a colocated relative file.

I fixed it in my case by configuring the plugin with a `babel-plugin-macros.config.js` file as follows (where the `artifactDirectory` is the same as the one supplied to the `relay-compiler`):

```js
module.exports = {
    relay: {
        artifactDirectory: "./src/ui/graphql/types",
    },
};
```

This solution assumes you are using the macro via `babel-plugin-macros`, otherwise you might need to supply that argument via the `.babelrc` file but I have no experience with that unfortunately.