# Create-react-app doesn't support relay compiler's --artifactDirectory option

Tags: create-react-app, relayjs

In the [relay docs](https://relay.dev/docs/guides/type-emission/), they nudge you to use the `--artifactDirectory` option for the relay compiler. This causes all the generated files to be placed in a single directory, which sounds like a very good idea to me! However, using this option causes a bunch of errors like this:

```
Failed to compile

./src/path/to/component/Component.tsx
Module not found: Can't resolve './__generated__/Component_field.graphql' in '/Users/me/path/to/project/src/path/to/component'
```

How do I use `relay-compiler`'s `--artifactDirectory` option in `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `babel-plugin-relay/macro` (or `babel-plugin-relay`) needs to be configured with the same option, or it will look for the generated files in a `./__generated__/` directory next to the source file. There is a description of how to do that in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61860888/6002977), but *configuring `babel-plugin-macros` is not possible in create-react-app*.